# facing error "type qualifier specified more than once" with c++ compiler

Tags: c++, c

i have header file as follows

```
**something.h**

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
blah
blah
extern CONST oMenu_t const menu[];
blah
blah
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

though i have used appropriate(i suppose) extern "C" still facing error "type qualifier specified more than once" while compiling with c++ compiler..
help please

Comment: You have two `const`. It doesn't matter whether you have `extern C` or not.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I compiled successfully a statement with multiple const using c compiler. I need to do this using c++ compiler. Actually i'm in project where there is mix of some c and c++ files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

multiple const is not needed
you may use:

```
extern oMenu_t const menu[];
```

in your .h file.
However, you must have something like below in one .c file (define only once, declare as many times, as used in .h)

```
oMenu_t const menu[] = {....}; // appropriate initializer
```

Comment: well, i was okay with this! I was curious if i can compile multiple consts with c without any error, how it can be done in c++ compiler using #ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

Comment: C++ compiler complains duplicate const if you use const more than once, C compiler also should, if it's a good one :-)

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
   #ifndef __FILENAME_HEADER_FILE
   #define __FILENAME_HEADER_FILE

your existing head file goes here...

    #endif // __FILENAME_HEADER_FILE
```

around your header file, this means you can include the .H many times but the compiler only sees it once.

FYI: Replace FILENAME with the name of your filename, the #define this needs to be different in each header file you use it.

Comment: hi i forgot to mention it in my question, sorry. its already implemented in my code.. thanks

Comment: symbols starting with underscore (_) should be used by compiler implementations. Symbols containing two underscore anywhere also. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier